# What is the use of isset() in PHP?

Tags: php

Can anyone please explain to me the usage of `isset` function in PHP with example.

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=what%20is%20php%20isset)

Comment: There's a rather extensive [**manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isset()` only returns boolean value i.e TRUE or FALSE.
Most oftent used to check if the variable is assinged or not

Let we check like this

**Case 1 :**

```
 $a = '';
 var_dump (isset($a)); // Will return TRUE
```

**Case 2 :**

```
$b = NULL;
var_dump (isset($a)); // Will return FALSE
```

**Case 3 :**

```
$c = 0;
var_dump (isset($c)); // Will return TRUE
```

**Case 4 :**

```
var_dump (isset($d)); // Will return FALSE
//oops i did'nt assing the variable.
```

Hope this helped you .

Answer (score 1):

Mostly used for form elements like check boxes . If the box is checked isset() returns true if its not returns false. Ca also be used to check if a variable has something assigned to it .

Answer (score 0):

check these links

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

http://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/isset.php

A simple explanation is, it is used to check whether a variable is set or not